# Single GUI interface for multiple python scripts (Different algorithms)

Tags: python, subprocess, optparse

I have written three python scripts that run just fine. My goal is to run those three scripts in a sequence via optparse_gui. The thing is that I was being able to perform via parsing the command line and with gui popping up for each script separately but that is not what I actually want, what I want is to use optparse_gui a single command with a single GUI interface which runs the first script and get its output and use it as an the input of the second script and use the output for the second script to be used as an input for the third script and generate the output. How can I do such thing? 
I was thinking of doing something like subprocess which allow to run three python programs but how can this be combined with the optparse_gui to allow for a single command through multiple python scripts to be run sequentially.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can "import" the other scripts and utilize their methods.

Comment: Create the 4th script that passes command-line arguments to other scripts and starts the pipeline:  `1st | 2nd | 3rd`